# Doubling the number of apostrophes in a string Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, apostrophe

Say the automatic input from the program is:

```
str = 'John's dog is called Ace'
```

I want to automatically re-create the string to contain another apostrophe, whenever a single apostrophe is found (as a single apostrophe "breaks" the string):

```
newstr = 'John''s dog is called Ace'
```

Note that this has to be done automatically i.e. through some kind of function. I cant just insert a new character manually.

What is the best and most efficient way to do this in Matlab? I am asking question because I know matlab has many functions that ease these tasks and do not necessarily always need whole string traversals (especially useful in very long strings). any kind of help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `regexprep`

```
newStr = regexprep ( str, '''', '''''' )
```

Comment: what happens if there is no apostrophe in str?

Comment: The original string is returned unaltered.

Comment: perfect. could I perhaps send you a msg somewhere to ask you a seperate question about matlab guide?

Comment: Just ask the new question on SO and I might be one of the ones to pick it up! :)

Comment: Nevermind, I already asked the question a million times and never got an answer that solved my problem. thanks for this one though :)

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `strrep`:

```
strrep('John''s dog''''s called Ace', '''', '''''')

ans =

John''s dog''''s called Ace
```

It looks odd in the example because of the escaping, so it may not be a good fit if you want it to be readable.

You could replace a `'` with char(39), which might cause less problems with errors but more with readability.

I also added a pair of quotes to make sure that worked and, hilariously, this results in a command with 18 single quotes in it. That's a personal best for me anyway.